# How to Bring One Form on Another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolbar

[image]

Here Form2 is Drawing Viewer And Form3 is toolbar when form2 is maximized form3 is get to back of form2. I want form3(Toolbar) on form3. if i minimize or maximize still form3 should be in front of form2. How can i bring form3 in front of form2

Comment: Then why it is a separate form? why not an user control or any other container?

Comment: Because i want DrawItem Event in combobox which is not available in toolstrip combobox

Answer (score 0):

In WinForms there is control named `statusStrip`. Maybe will be better to use it instead of new form.

Anyway, if you want to do it in your way, you can put in your `Form2` to the bottom `Panel`, in which you can load your `Form3` to.

Answer (score 0):

Try using in a method where you have shown form 2

```
 Form Form2 = new Form();
 Form2.MdiParent = this;
 Form2.Show();
```

Refer below link for more details :

```
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3553/Introduction-to-MDI-Forms-with-C
```

Comment: i used same code. Both form2 and form3 is child of form1